# how to render a page in node express from a route.post?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post, ejs

I have a page that fetches 100 memes from an api. it shows the memes in a table and each one has a details button that takes the user to a details page for the meme. I have to do a POST request to the meme route and render the meme details page. The post request is succesfull, but the meme page is not rendering from my render() in my router.post.

Meme.js

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json();
var ensureLogIn = require("connect-ensure-login").ensureLoggedIn;
var ensureLoggedIn = ensureLogIn();


router.post("/", ensureLoggedIn, jsonParser, (req, res, next) => {
  const meme = req.body.meme;
  const user = req.body.user;
  try {
    res.render("meme", { meme: meme, user: user });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
  }
});


module.exports = router;
```

memes.ejs button:

```
          <tbody>
            <% memes.forEach(meme=> { %>
              <tr class="meme-row <%= viewedMemeIds.includes(meme.id) ? 'viewed' : '' %>" data-meme-id="<%= meme.id %>">
                <td><img src="<%= meme.url %>" alt="<%= meme.name %>"></td>
                <td>
                  <%= meme.name %>
                </td>
                <% if (user) { %>
                  <td>
                    <button class="btn-meme details-button" onclick="handleDetailsClick(<%= JSON.stringify(meme) %>, <%= JSON.stringify(user) %>)">Details</button>
                  </td>
                  <% } %>
              </tr>
              <% }) %>
          </tbody>
```

MemeDetails.js:

```
async function handleDetailsClick(meme, user) {
  try {
    // Make a POST request to the meme route with the meme and user data
    const response = await fetch("/meme", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ meme, user }),
    });

    // Handle the response status
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
    }

  } catch (error) {
    // Handle any errors
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

response in terminal is: POST /meme 200 10.677 ms - 2703, but nothing renders on the page.

Answer (score 2):

firstly I want to mention about "*but nothing renders on the page*".

It will never render the page automatically since it's mentioned in the [MDN Webdocs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) that `fetch()` is used for fetch resources from network using AJAX calls. The resources you've fetched will be stored on `response` variable and you need to manually process the fetched data (whether manipulating the DOM innerText or redirect to another page e.g using `window.href.location`)

But, POST request normally used for create/modify data on the server (please read about [HTTP METHODS](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)). I saw you use the POST request to render a page / navigating to another page. GET is the HTTP method that is used to request data from server.

I think it's better for you to change the way you handle the `handleDetailsClick`. Instead of passing the whole meme data, you can use the meme ID in the query string of GET method using HTML element like `<a href=".../meme?id=<%= meme.id %>">` or simply modify the `onclick` behavior of `<button>` element to have `window.location.href=".../meme?id=<%= meme.id %>"`

Then, in the express side you can modify the POST route to GET and get the specific ID in query string, so you can search it from database etc and  render the page using `res.render()` like in the example below.

```js
app.get("/meme", function (req, res) {
    const memeID = req.query.id;

    // Fetch the meme details from DB or any other data sources using the specified ID
    const memeDetails = db.findById(memeID);

    res.render("pages/meme", { memeDetails });
});
```

Hope it helps

**Updated**

As you mentioned about the requirement of assignment, you can modify a bit the above code for the POST route (you can use only ID or the whole data depend on the assignment requirement), instead of using `res.render()` to render an html page, you can simply use `res.JSON()` and utilize the [JSON](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp) response using JS.

Meme.js

```js
app.post("/meme", function (req, res) {
    const memeID = req.body.id;

    // Fetch the meme details from DB or any other data sources using the specified ID
    const memeDetails = db.findById(memeID);

    res.json({
        success: true,
        data: {
            id  : memeDetails.id,
            name: memeDetails.name,
            url : memeDetails.url,
        }
    })
});
```

meme.ejs (you can put any element that will be a container for selected details meme)

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <% memes.forEach(meme=> { %>
      <tr class="meme-row <%= viewedMemeIds.includes(meme.id) ? 'viewed' : '' %>" data-meme-id="<%= meme.id %>">
        <td><img src="<%= meme.url %>" alt="<%= meme.name %>"></td>
        <td>
          <%= meme.name %>
        </td>
        <% if (user) { %>
          <td>
            <button class="btn-meme details-button" onclick="handleDetailsClick(<%= meme.id %>)">Details</button>
           </td>
        <% } %>
      </tr>
    <% }) %>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div id="selectedMeme"></div>
```

then for the MemeDetails.js

```js
async function handleDetailsClick(id) {
  try {
    // Make a POST request to the meme route with the meme id
    const response = await fetch("/meme", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: { id },
    });

    // Handle the response status
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
    }
    
    // Handle the response (convert to JSON and utilize it)
    const jsonResp = await response.json();
    if (!jsonResp.success) {
      throw new Error("Something is error");
    }
    
    // put the fetched data to HTML
    const memeData = jsonResp.data;
    document.getElementById('selectedMeme').innerHTML = `
      <b>Meme name: ${memeData.name}</b>
      <br />Meme url: <a href="${memeData.url}">Click me</a>
    `;

  } catch (error) {
    // Handle any errors
    console.error(error);
    document.getElementById('selectedMeme').innerHTML = '';
  }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly how I would do it normally, with a query ID in the link and a post.get. The thing is that this is a school assignment. and it says the following: "When a table row's 'Details' button is clicked in the Memes Overview view, the click event needs to utilize a JavaScript function, created in a JavaScript file in the correct folder, to POST the information to the meme route to open the Meme Details view and display the correct information for the selected meme. The meme details route needs to accept a POST and not a GET to show the selected meme.". I dont get it...

Comment: You can take a look on my updated answer. Hope it helps